# ¿Como modificar el número de decimales que muestra marcador en gráfica?

Tags: java, android

Estoy utilizando LineChart para poder generar una gráfica y representar ciertos valores.

Esta gráfica la obtengo de la siguiente librería: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1

Mi problema viene a la hora de ver los puntos dibujados en la gráfica ya que me muestra dichos puntos con 3 decimales y los valores que le paso yo son con 0, 1 o 2 decimales, nunca con 3.

Por ejemplo, si le paso 1.2 en la gráfica me muestra 1.200.

[image: Ejemplo de la gráfica]

Como se ve, todos los valores me los muestra con 3 decimales.

La forma que genero los puntos es la siguiente:

```
entries.add(new Entry((float) listaFechasOrig[listaDatos.length - 1 - i].getTime(), Float.parseFloat(datoOrigRecortado.replace(",","."))));
```

Ahí, los valores se pasan correctamente (con los decimales deseados).

El marcador que utilizo es uno personalizado que hereda de MarkerView, este es el código pero aquí no es donde lo redondea.

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView {

private TextView tvContent;
private Context cont;

public CustomMarkerView (Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);
    // this markerview only displays a textview
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    cont = context;

}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    Date d = new Date((long)e.getX());
    String fecha = d.toString().substring(0,20);

    fecha = fecha.replace("Jan", "Ene");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Apr", "Abr");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Aug", "Ago");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Dec", "Dic");

    fecha = fecha.replace("Mon", "Lunes");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Tue", "Martes");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Wed", "Miércoles");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Thu", "Jueves");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Fri", "Viernes");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Sat", "Sábado");
    fecha = fecha.replace("Sun", "Domingo");

    try
    {
        Tab1Prueba.rellenaDatos(fecha, e.getY()+"");
    }catch(Exception exc)
    {}

    try
    {
        Tab1Gra.rellenaDatos(fecha, e.getY()+"");
    }catch(Exception exc)
    {}
}

@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    // this will center the marker-view horizontally
    return -(getWidth() / 2);
}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
    return -getHeight();
}
}
```

Pensaba que era una propiedad del Marker pero yo no le he puesto nada (no se si viene de la clase que heredo) o hay que cambiar algún atributo de la gráfica y no del marcador.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es usar un formateador que proporciona la propia librería, como se explica [aqui](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface).

Primero implemmentas el interfaz `IValueFormatter`

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // usar un decimal        }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // escribe aqui tu logica
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $"; // por ejemplo,agregar un simbolo de dolar
    }
}
```

Y para usarlo,simplemente llamas al método `setValueFormatter` pasándole tu clase como parámetro:

```
// uso en un objeto de datos completo
lineData.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());

// uso en un objeto de datos individual
lineDataSet.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```